# Leap Motion error: Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread Abort trap: 6

Tags: python, leap-motion

I have no experience programming Leap Motion, and I tried to run the Sample.py file on python2.7 (on IOS Sierra, 10.12.3). However, it always give me the following error:
    Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
    Abort trap: 6

When I try

```
which python2.7
```

I get

```
/opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

When I run

```
otool -L LeapPython.so
```

I get

```
LeapPython.so:
    /opt/local/bin/python2.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    @loader_path/libLeap.dylib (compatibility version 0.7.0, current version 2.3.1)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
```

I have a few python versions in my OS. When I run `sudo port select --list python`
I get

```
Available versions for python:
    none
    python26-apple
    python27
    python27-apple (active)
```

What is happening...Please help!! Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 2):

Getting leap motion to work with python distributions installed through ports or brew require a few extra steps.  So for ease, use the default system python.

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

then check it with:

```
which python
```

At which point you should get:

```
/usr/local/bin/python27
```

Now I would re-try with the SDK, running the sample.py.

If you want to use a ports version, you will have to select the port version, which lies in :

```
/opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

and then run the otool utility to display the current loader paths:

```
otool -L LeapPython.so
```

Which will display output similar to:

```
LeapPython.so:
    @loader_path/LeapPython.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    @loader_path/libLeap.dylib (compatibility version 0.7.0, current version 2.0.1)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
```

The line starting with, /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python is the reference to Python, which needs to be changed with the install_name_tool utility.

Second, run the install_name_tool utility to update the Python reference to the desired location. For example:

```
install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python \
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib \
LeapPython.so
```

Hopefully that should do it.  But as I said, if you are using the mac distribution in /usr/local/bin/, then it is more straighforward and you do not need these two steps.

Full doc from leap here: 
https://community.leapmotion.com/t/python-thread-error-mavericks/1184/4

Comment: Thank you! but when I tried to do sudo port select --set python python27, the python path I get after is still /opt/local/bin/python, instead of /opt/local/bin/python27. So it doesn't really work :(